# Question about smooth functions?

Tags: calculus

I know the definition of a smooth function. I understand why the function needs to be differentiable but why we need the derivative to be continuous?

Comment: Smooth normally means infinitely differentiable: that is, that we can continue taking derivatives as many times as we like. In particular, to take second derivatives we require that the first derivative be differentiable and hence continuous..

Comment: OK. But let say we are talking only about one-time smooth function. Why is the condition for the first derivative to be continuous?

Comment: A differentiable function need not have continuous derivative (e.g. $f(x) = x^2 sin(\frac{1}{x})$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(0) = 0$). Functions which are $C^1$ (which is what you mean by one time smooth?) are continuously differentiable - they are simply defined this way.

Comment: There is nothing like geometrical intuition behind the definition?

Comment: Derivatives can never have jump discontinuities : the only discontinuity a derivative can have is the sort of really horrible one that $f'(x)$ from above will have at 0. I suppose we require continuously differentiable functions precisely in order to rule out really horrible examples like that.

Comment: @ODF A counter-example is $f(x)=0$ for $x\le0$ and $f(x)=x^{2}$ for $x > 0$. Its second derivative has a jump discontinuity at $x=0$.

Comment: Its first derivative isn't differentiable at 0.